# How to know that your application is not responding?

Tags: c#

I have such particular code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SingleR_mustBeWorkedUp._number_of_Requestes; i++)
{   
    Random myRnd = new Random(SingleR_mustBeWorkedUp._num_path);
    while (true)
    {    
        int k = myRnd.Next(start, end);
        if (CanRequestBePutted(timeLineR, k, SingleR_mustBeWorkedUp._time_service, start + end) == true) 
        {
            SingleR_mustBeWorkedUp.placement[i] = k;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I use an infinite loop here which will end only if `CanRequestBePutted` returns `true`. So how to know that the app isn't responding?

There is a solution by controlling time of working each loop, but it doesn't seem to be really good. And I can't forecast that is going to happen in every cases.

Any solutions?

Comment: Your code looks wrong, particularly with the `if` and the code following the `if` (e.g. the `break`).

Comment: Responding to _what_?  The code it not _hung_, it's just continually looping until `CanRequestBePutted` returns true.  Under what conditions would that happen>

Comment: The application won't respond anymore if it stops responding, I'm not sure what kind of answer you expect. And this is not an infinite loop: it will break out of the `while` at the end of the first iteration.

Comment: Also you should put new `new Random()` block _outside_ the `while` loop - otherwise you'll get the same random number each time since you're seeding it (even if it's a different number each time there's no need to re-seed a random number generator for each loop)

Comment: if you continue to change the code in question will be difficult to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're concerned that this operation could potentially take long enough for the application's user to notice, you should be running it in a non-UI thread.  Then you can be sure that it will not be making your application unrepsonsive.  You should only be running it in the UI thread if you're *sure* it will *always* complete very quickly.  When in doubt, go to a non-UI thread.

Don't try to figure out dynamically whether the operation will take a long time or not.  If it taking a while is a possibility, do the work in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a task or threadpool so you're not blocking and put a timer on it?

The task could look something like this:

```
//put a class level variable
static object _padlock = new object();

var tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < SingleR_mustBeWorkedUp._number_of_Requestes; i++)
{
    var task = new Task(() =>
       {
           Random myRnd = new Random(SingleR_mustBeWorkedUp._num_path);
           while (true)
           {
              int k = myRnd.Next(start, end);
              if (CanRequestBePutted(timeLineR, k, SingleR_mustBeWorkedUp._time_service, start + end) == true)
              {
                   lock(_padlock)
                      SingleR_mustBeWorkedUp.placement[i] = k;
                   break;
              }
            }
       });
     task.Start();
     tasks.Add(task);
} 
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

However I would also try to figure out a way to take out your while(true), which is a bit dangerous.  Also Task requires .NET 4.0 or above and i'm not sure what framework your targeting.

If you need something older you can use ThreadPool.

Also you might want to put locks around shared resources like SingleR_mustBeWorkedUp.placement or anywhere else might be changing a variable.  I put one around SingleR_mustBeWorkedUp.placement as an example.

Comment: This code, as it stands, will deadlock.  Also, it's unclear if the iterations of the loop should be run in parallel.  They may not have been designed to be thread safe in such a situation.

Comment: It'll deadlock because of the while loop?

Comment: Nope.  It certainly will not.  The while loop will be broken out of as soon as the given conditional check returns true.

Comment: @Servy Why will it deadlock?  Yes, i'm assuming each request can run in parallel.  Based on the details and variable name, I think it's a safe assumption.  Your right about there might need to be some thread safe locking and I should have mentioned that.

Comment: It will deadlock because you never start any of the tasks.  There are a number of field of an unknown type being called, as well as an instance method being called.  It's entirely possible that there is some form of state modified within that method, which would cause race conditions, if the code would ever actually run.

Comment: @Servy I did forgot to start the task but that would make it block at WaitAll and not deadlock.  I will change the code.

Comment: @Servy I don't think it would deadlock if the task never started.  Also, don't think there will be a race condition(Even if it started) because there is no locking to create race condition.  Anyway, there might need to be some type of thread safe locking that needs to be added.

Comment: So One major issue that you have is that you're closing over the loop variable, and then executing all of the operations in parallel.  That's almost certainly going to cause it to break.  Next, not having synchronization over access to shared resources can *absolutely* create race conditions.  You don't need to have locks to create race conditions.  In fact, locks exist to *avoid* problematic race conditions.